# Polymer expression: Only identifier function invocations are allowed

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have an object, User, it has a function getFullName(), user passed to a polymer component vi standard attribute binding. I want to display full user name, for this I want to call getFullName() in the expression.

I'm getting the error:

Error: Only identifier function invocations are allowed {stack: (...), message: "Only identifier function invocations are allowed"}

What I'm not doing right?

function:

```
getFullName : function() {
  return this.user ? 
   ( this.user.firstname + ' ' +  this.user.lastname ) : '';
}
```

polymer component:

```
<polymer-element name="user-header" attributes="user">
 <template>
    <div>Hello User: {{ user.getFullName() }}</div>
 </template>    
 <script>
 Polymer({
    publish: {
         user :  {value: null, reflect: true},
       }
 });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase polymer is not able bind to function. It can be only variable(property of object)

Comment: looks like, cause when I made it a property setter/getter, all start working, but what the hell "identifier function" is?

Comment: An identifier function is a function that acts as/on (part or whole) a member of an object. It can only be invoked by accessing that member and only sets or returns the data of that member. For instance, you cannot call `object.property.get()`, so the `get()` is actually associated with the `property` identifier. *(I'm not sure I like the proprietary terminology, but I understand it. Really, its just a special way to say getter/setter...)*